stream multiplication of array with time complexity O(n)
I have an array of elements as below:
int arr[]={1,2,3,4}

now I need the result array as below:
{24,12,8,6}
So basically it will multiply each element expect the ith element.
For index 0: it will take arr[1]*arr[2]*arr[3]
For index 1: it will take arr[0]*arr[2]*arr[3]
I have resolved the problem as below but with o(n*n)
But, we need a solution with o(n).
public int[] calculate(int[] arr){
    int len=arr.length;
    int[] arr1=new int[len];
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
        int result=1;
        for(int j=0;j<len;j++){
            if(i!=j){
                result=result*arr[j];

            }
        }arr1[i]=result;
    }
    return arr1;

}


Compute a*b*c*d.  Call that prod  Now, replace element a with prod/a.

thanks..solution--> int prod = Arrays.stream(arr).reduce(1, (x, y) -> x * y);
return IntStream.range(0, arr.length).map(x -> prod / arr[x]).toArray();

You can just multiply all elements (P) and then generate P/vi for each vi.
With Java 8 streams:
int prod = Arrays.stream(array).reduce(1, (x,y)->x*y);
var result = Array.stream(array).map(v -> prod/v).toArray();

Without streams:
int prod = 1;
for (int e: array) prod *= e;
int[] result = new int[array.lenght];
for (int e: array) result[i] = prod/e;

